# Reactjs change background of Quizcard onClick

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, event-handling, rendering

I would like to change the backgroundColor of a span onClick, depending if its the correct answer or not... If it's not the correct answer, I make it red, otherwise green...
I just can't get my head around why this does not work... In my `handleClick` function, I set the background to red (tried with 2 different ways), but on the first click, nothing happens, only on the second click then changes the component to red, why?
I also already assumed it has to do with rendering twice or so.. but I dont understand why.

The critical part is here: `{quiz.allAnswers.map((answer, index) => ( <span ...` I am doing the handleClick there for the span (for every answer)...

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import NavbarCollapse from 'react-bootstrap/esm/NavbarCollapse'
import easySVG from '../../assets/images/svg/feather.svg'
import middleSVG from '../../assets/images/svg/balance.svg'
import hardSVG from '../../assets/images/svg/muscle.svg'
import wrongAnswerSVG from '../../assets/images/svg/wrong.svg'
import correctAnswerSVG from '../../assets/images/svg/correct.svg'

function Quizcard({
    hasChosen,
    gameFinished,
    quiz,
    nrOfQuestions,
    questionNr,
    correct_answer,
    incrCount,
    checkAnswer,
    correctAnswerCount,
    actualNr,
}) {
    const [isCorrect, setIsCorrect] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('inside Quizcard use Effect!')
        console.log('chosen:', hasChosen)
        console.log('Quiz:', quiz)
    })

    const handleClick = (e, answer, correct_answer, corrAnswerReference) => {
        if (answer != correct_answer) {
            console.log(e.currentTarget)
            //e.currentTarget.classList.add('bg-red-400')
            e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
        }
        if (!hasChosen) {
            checkAnswer(e, answer, correct_answer, corrAnswerReference)
        }
    }

    const corrAnswerReference = useRef()
    return (
        <div className="max-w-md mx-auto bg-blue-500 rounded-md shadow-quizBox border-1 border-gray-300">
            <div
                className="text-white capitalize tracking-wider leading-8 bg-blue-500 px-3  rounded-md"
                id="quizCategory">
                {decodeURIComponent(quiz.category)}
            </div>
            <div
                className="text-indigo-400 flex align-center content-center justify-between  bg-blue-900 px-3"
                id="quizDifficulty">
                <span className="text-xs">
                    Question {questionNr} of {nrOfQuestions}
                </span>
                {quiz.difficulty === 'easy' ? (
                    <span className="text-green-400 capitalize inline-block ml-4 text-xs    ">
                        {quiz.difficulty}
                        <img
                            src={easySVG}
                            className="h-4 w-4 text-center inline-block ml-1"
                            alt="easy"
                        />
                    </span>
                ) : quiz.difficulty === 'medium' ? (
                    <span className="text-yellow-400 capitalize inline-block ml-4  text-xs">
                        {quiz.difficulty}
                        <img
                            src={middleSVG}
                            className="h-4 w-4 text-center inline-block ml-1"
                            alt="medium"
                        />
                    </span>
                ) : (
                    <span className="text-red-500 capitalize inline-block ml-4  text-xs">
                        {quiz.difficulty}
                        <img
                            src={hardSVG}
                            className="h-4 w-4 text-center inline-block ml-1"
                            alt="hard"
                        />
                    </span>
                )}
            </div>{' '}
            <div className="bg-gray-50 flex">
                <section
                    className="px-3 leading-normal text-sm pt-4 pb-4 w-3/5"
                    id="quizQuestion">
                    {decodeURIComponent(quiz.question)}
                </section>{' '}
                <section
                    className="px-2 pt-4 pb-4 text-sm break-normal text-right w-1/2 pr-5 space-y-2 rounded-md"
                    id="quizAnswers">
                    {quiz.allAnswers.map((answer, index) => (
                        <span
                            ref={
                                answer === correct_answer
                                    ? corrAnswerReference
                                    : null
                            }
                            key={index}
                            className={`flex justify-start align-right text-right content-center items-center  relative ${
                                !gameFinished &&
                                hasChosen &&
                                answer === correct_answer
                                    ? 'bg-green-400'
                                    : ''
                            }`}
                            onClick={e =>
                                handleClick(
                                    e,
                                    answer,
                                    correct_answer,
                                    corrAnswerReference
                                )
                            }>
                            <button className="bg-gray-300 rounded-full hover:bg-green-500 hover:text-white shadow-sm border-solid border-2 border-blue-600 outline-none cursor-pointer font-semibold pt-1.5 pr-3 pb-1.5 pl-3 m-1 leading-6 text-lg inline-block ">
                                {index === 0
                                    ? 'A'
                                    : index === 1
                                    ? 'B'
                                    : index === 2
                                    ? 'C'
                                    : 'D'}
                            </button>
                            <p className="text-left pl-1 " key={index}>
                                {decodeURIComponent(answer)}
                                {!gameFinished && hasChosen && (
                                    <img
                                        className="h-6 2-6 absolute inline right-0 fill-current text-green-800"
                                        src={
                                            answer === correct_answer
                                                ? correctAnswerSVG
                                                : null
                                        }
                                    />
                                )}
                            </p>
                        </span>
                    ))}
                </section>
            </div>
            <section className="bg-gray-800 w-full h-auto flex justify-between content-center align-middle text-center ">
                <span className="text-white text-sm align-center ml-3">
                    Score: {correctAnswerCount}/{nrOfQuestions}
                </span>
                <button
                    className="text-sm text-white inline-block"
                    onClick={incrCount}>
                    Continue
                    <svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        className="h-5 w-5 inline ml-2 mr-3 pr-1"
                        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                        fill="white">
                        <path
                            fillRule="evenodd"
                            d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm3.707-8.707l-3-3a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414L10.586 9H7a1 1 0 100 2h3.586l-1.293 1.293a1 1 0 101.414 1.414l3-3a1 1 0 000-1.414z"
                            clipRule="evenodd"
                        />
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </section>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Quizcard
```

Comment: use component state, and update that in the handler , then use that state in html element classlist with help of classnames library to change classes dynamically.

Comment: Can't really say for sure. Looks like it should work, assuming the component has `correct_answer` set correctly and you click the correct answer. It is a very non-typical way to use React though. You shouldn't try to manipulate DOM directly like that, but instead set the selected answer to state, and use a CSS class to style the selected wrong answers to red.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I first tried to save the currentTarget element in state from upper state parent component (QuizList) and pass that element property down to the quiz after clicked and then trying to set color state in useEffect on that element, but didnt work. I guess maybe because that element's not the same anymore after re-rendering the Quizcard.

So the solution was pretty easy, I instead pushed the index of that answer to my clickHandler, and up to my checkAnswer(...,index,..) function which resides in my Quizlist component one state above. I passed the index then down again together with the property "hasChosen" to know that the answer has been chosen.
Then I just set the background color on the answer property with the corresponding index like so:

```
<span ...
 className={`flex justify-start align-right text-right content-center items-center relative ${
                                !gameFinished &&
                                hasChosen &&
                                answer === correct_answer
                                    ? 'bg-green-400'
                                    : hasChosen && checkedIndex == index
                                    ? 'bg-red-400'
                                    : ''
                            }`}</span>
```

With the index comparison it worked like a charm :)